# How to add extra onClick handler along with the user's onClick on the button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've to extend the default `onClick` functionality on the button. If a user clicks on it the user's `onClick` should trigger, but I also have to extend it with triggering my own function with the user's `onClick`.

I've tried two approaches

1. With HOC
2. React.cloneElement

**`I'm not able to figure out which one to choose. Why choose one over the other? Which one is efficient?`**

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**App.jsx**

```
import "./styles.css";
import Wrap from "./Wrap";
import EnhancedButton from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  function defaultOnClick() {
    console.log("default on click");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrap>
        <button onClick={defaultOnClick}> count </button>
      </Wrap>

      <EnhancedButton onClick={defaultOnClick}>
        click from enhanced button
      </EnhancedButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Button.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import HOC from "./HOC";

function Button({ children, onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
}

export default HOC(Button);
```

**Wrap.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

export default function WrapWithOnclick(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  function customWrapOnclick() {
    console.log("customWrapOnclick");
  }

  return (
    <>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onClick: (e) => {
            customWrapOnclick(e);
            child.props.onClick && child.props.onClick(e);
          }
        });
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

**HOC.jsx**

```
export default function HOC(Component) {
  return function ModifiedComponent(props) {
    const { children, onClick: hocOnClick, ...rest } = props;

    function customHOCOnclick() {
      console.log("customHOCOnclick");
    }
    return (
      <>
        <Component
          onClick={(e) => {
            customHOCOnclick(e);
            hocOnClick && hocOnClick();
          }}
          {...rest}
        >
          {children}
        </Component>
      </>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean extend it? Does it have a default behaviour when the user clicks the button?

Comment: Seems like an opion based question and i think it's better use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tasos Let's say the user provide the default `onClick` handler and I've to add another `onClick`. So when button clicks then both of the function should trigger...

Comment: How is the default onCLick provided? Is it inside a form and it triggers a `onSubmit` event?

Comment: @Tasos like normal `onClick` button that is passed to `button`

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the cloneElement approach neither the HOC to be honest. What I would do is this:

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ children, onClick }) {
  const localOnclick = () => {
    //... do stuff ...
    onClick && onClick()
  }
  return <LibraryButton onClick={localOnclick}>{children}</LibraryButton>;
}

export default Button;
```

It's pretty straight forward and very simple.
Does it cover your case?

Comment: No, I don't have control over the button that is passed to me. consider that button from the library. I just have to add another onClick handler.

Comment: The simply replace `<button>` inside my function with the library's button (like a HOC)

Comment: I updated it. It would help though if you could add more about this button that you use